# Error while trying to search on hash indexed file

Tags: c, indexing, hash, hashtable, binaryfiles

I'm using a hash table to index a csv file containing Uber-Movement data of travel time between different areas of a city, the fields used are sourceid (origin), dstid (destination), hod (hour of the day), mean_travel_time (travel time). I'm using 1160 buckets because that is the number of areas available, I index every register with hash function (module), also use linked list to handle collisions and save it as a binary file, here's the full code of the process

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define casillas 1160

typedef struct {
    int sourceid;
    int dstid;
    int hod;
    float mean_travel_time;
    float standard_deviation_travel_time;
    float geometric_mean_travel_time;
    float geometric_standard_deviation_travel_time;
} Viaje;

typedef struct _Nodo {
    Viaje viaje;
    struct _Nodo* siguiente;
} Nodo;

int hash(int sourceid) {
    return sourceid % casillas;
}

void insertar_en_lista(Viaje viaje, Nodo* tabla_hash[]) {
    int indice = hash(viaje.sourceid);
    Nodo* nuevo_nodo = (Nodo*) malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    nuevo_nodo->viaje = viaje;
    nuevo_nodo->siguiente = tabla_hash[indice]; 
    tabla_hash[indice] = nuevo_nodo; // --> new node is now first node
}

int main(){
    FILE* archivo = fopen("viajes.csv", "r");
    char linea[1024];
    fgets(linea, 1024, archivo); // Descartamos la primera línea (cabecera)
    Nodo* tabla_hash[casillas] = {NULL}; // Inicializamos la tabla hash con punteros nulos
    while (fgets(linea, 1024, archivo)) {
        Viaje viaje;
        sscanf(linea, "%d,%d,%d,%f,%f,%f,%f",
            &viaje.sourceid,
            &viaje.dstid,
            &viaje.hod,
            &viaje.mean_travel_time,
            &viaje.standard_deviation_travel_time,
            &viaje.geometric_mean_travel_time,
            &viaje.geometric_standard_deviation_travel_time
        );
        insertar_en_lista(viaje, tabla_hash);
    }
    fclose(archivo);

    archivo = fopen("index.bin", "wb");
    for (int i = 0; i < casillas; i++) {
        Nodo* nodo_actual = tabla_hash[i];
        while (nodo_actual) {
            fwrite(&nodo_actual->viaje, sizeof(Viaje), 1, archivo);
            nodo_actual = nodo_actual->siguiente;
        }
    }
    fclose(archivo);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I need to find an specific route between areas given, source , destination and hour, and using hash() find the index and get to the wanted place in the file, the thing is when I check with breakpoints, for example using 1140 as sourceid, the hash function calculates the index and fseek works, but the first travel it checks isn't one with 1140 sourceid its one with 1160 sourceid, as if it is checking every file in descending order. Here's the code for the search

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define casillas 1160
void exit(int _code);

typedef struct {
    int sourceid;
    int dstid;
    int hod;
    float mean_travel_time;
    float standard_deviation_travel_time;
    float geometric_mean_travel_time;
    float geometric_standard_deviation_travel_time;
} Viaje;

int hash(int sourceid) {
    return sourceid % casillas;
}

float buscarTiempoViaje(int sourceid, int dstid, int hod, FILE* archivo) {
    int indice = hash(sourceid);
    Viaje viaje;
    int result = fseek(archivo, indice * sizeof(Viaje), SEEK_SET); // Apuntamos al inicio de la lista correspondiente
    printf("%ld\n", indice*sizeof(viaje));
    printf("%ld\n", ftell(archivo));
    if(result < 0){
        perror("No se pudo hallar la lista correspondiente al índice calculado");
        exit(-1);
    }
    while (fread(&viaje, sizeof(Viaje), 1, archivo) == 1) {
        if(viaje.sourceid == indice){
            if (viaje.sourceid == sourceid && viaje.dstid == dstid && viaje.hod == hod) {
                return viaje.mean_travel_time;
            }
        }
    }
    // Si llegamos aquí, no se encontró el viaje
    viaje.sourceid = -1;
    printf("NA\n");
    return -1;
}
```

My intention is to join same sourceid travels in the same linked list and search in it, but don't know exactly what is the bug here. I don't know if it is the way I'm opening or saving it, the search works if I'm pointing to the first indexed travel but then the while loop doesn't continue.

Comment: If any of the buckets are empty or there is more than one entry in the list it seems the value you're using to seek will be incorrect. `if(viaje.sourceid == indice)` also seems incorrect as one side is a hashed value and the other is a value before hashing.

Answer (score 0):

> using a hash table to index a csv file
> using hash() find the index

This approach fails as the `hash()` does not return the `i`th element of the data set, but the *hash index*.  This may be more or less than the `i`th element.

The loop `while (fread(&viaje, sizeof(Viaje), 1, archivo) == 1) {` only walks forward if a match is not found.  It may have to walk backwards to find `viaje.sourceid == indice`.

---

**Alternatives**

- Sort the hash table before writing and then use [secant seach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method) to find.
- Use an [AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree).

---

Tip: typically fewer hash collisions when the hash table size is prime.

```
// #define casillas 1160
#define casillas 1163 /* Next prime */
```